# Losing data in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Overall: Our code gets data from Snowflake (=data warehouse), performs certain transformations on it in Python with Spark, and pushes it back to Snowflake.

When I perform this task on my computer, things go well: #inputrows = #outputrows. When someone performs it on their computer, data gets lost. The data that gets lost is random: every time this person performs the task, both differen rows and a different amount of rows is returned. Also performing the task on an EMR doesn't return the right number of rows. We perform the exact same spark-submit command.

We believe it is not in the 'writing to snowflake' part, as performing `counts` in the code already gives the wrong number of rows before writing to Snowflake.

Is it somehow possible to loose data when using Spark?